# @JsonSerialize(include=JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_EMPTY) is not considered

Tags: json, null, jackson, jsonserializer

I have annotated a POJO on class level with

```
@org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonSerialize(include=JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_EMPTY)
```

(annotating on method level doesn't work either) but null values will be serialized though. 
In my POM I have

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

How can I achieve that null values will NOT be serialized?

Comment: Can you post a fully qualified name of the annotation type? It could be that your are mixing Jackson 1.x and 2.x classes.

Comment: I think @AlexeyGavrilov got it: Jersey still uses Jackson 1.x, and you are probably using Jackson 2.x annotations.

Comment: See above, please. Eclipse's code completion does NOT find @JsonInclude.... Trying @JsonInclude(Include.xxx) fails too.